# grep lines containing specific string (a line can be written on max 3 lines)

Tags: linux, shell

I need to get all log done in my project.
I'm using this command to do that:

```
grep -rnw $1 -e "Logger.[view]*;$" >> log.txt
```

this line return all lines containing Logger.[one of the these caracters]
contained in the project directory "`$1`" except that there are some lines written on 2 or 3 lines (IDE formating). In this case I get only the first line only.
What can I do to get the complete text of that log knowing that a log line will always end with "`);`"
example of such line :

```
Logger.v(xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx);
```

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
echo "Hello Logger!
# get project path 
echo "project directory is $1"
# get all project logs and store them into temporary file tmp.txt for processing
grep -rnw $1 -e "Logger.[view]" >> tmp.txt
echo "tmp.txt created successfully"
# remove package name from previous result and store result into log.txt
sed -r 's/.{52}//' tmp.txt >> log.txt
echo "log.txt created successfully"
```

grep command return **file_path**/**file_name** : **line_number** : **line**.
I found this command that returns only the **line** even if it is written in 2 or 3 lines but without the **file_path** **file_name** and the **line_number**

```
sed -n '/Logger.[viewd]/{:start /;/!{N;b start};/Logger.[viewd]/p}' Main.java
```

Is there a way to have those two results combined.
example :

```
/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/Main.java:97:Logger.i(xxxxxxxxxxxxx);    
/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/Main.java:106:Logger.d(yyyyyyyyyyyy
    yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy);
```

Comment: Sorry, my answer wasn't complete, deleting it until i get time to look at it again.

Comment: Maybe look into http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112132/how-can-i-grep-patterns-across-multiple-lines ?

Comment: Do you always need the FULL lines, i.e. if a line looks like `xxxxxx Logger.v(yyyy`, do you need the xxxxxx too? If not, your question boils down to "find all strings matching the regexp `/Logger\.[view]\(.+?\)/m`. If your files are not so overisized that they don't fit into memory, it might be more convenient (also to debug and maintain) to use a tiny program (Ruby, Perl, Python,....), slurp the file into a string, and run the regexp on the string.

Comment: Yes I need that xxxxxx too. In fact that xxxxxx containes the file name in which we have writen the log line. I'll be using that file name after.

Comment: the link http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112132/how-can-i-grep-patterns-across-multiple-lines is usefull.
I tried this command on one file and it returned a good result:
`sed -n '/Logger.[viewd]/{:start /;/!{N;b start};/Logger.[viewd]/p}' MainActivity.java`
the only problem I have is that this command returns the line beginning from **Logger** (It removes the first part of the line which I'll need after)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem and here is my code:

```
# get all project logs and store them into log.txt for processing
for i in $(find -name "*.java")
do
echo  >> log.txt
echo "**************** file $i ********************************" >> log.txt
echo  >> log.txt
    grep -rnw Logger.[viewd] $i | while read -r line ; do

    # remove breaklines from first line to avoid having bad results
    line="$(echo $line | sed $'s/\r//')"

    # if first line ends with ");" print it to log file
    if [[ ${line: -2} == ");" ]]; then
        echo $line >> log.txt

    # else get next line also
    else
        # get second line number
        line_number="$(echo "$line" | cut -d : -f1)"
        next_line_number=$((line_number+1))
        # get second line
        next_line=$(sed "${next_line_number}q;d" $i | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')
        # concatenate first line & second line
        line="$line $next_line"
        # print resulting line to log file
        echo $line >> log.txt
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that's a break line problem. Try to replace `grep -rnw $1 -e "Logger.[view]" >> tmp.txt` by the following lines:

```
for i in `ls $1`;
do
 cat $1/$i | tr '\n' ' ' | grep -rnw -e "Logger.[view]" >> tmp.txt
done
```

Here, `tr '\n' ' '` replace the break line by a simple space.

Comment: `$1` is a directory not a file so we can not execute cat command on it

Comment: Sorry i think that was a log file. So i will modify my answer !